# Ajax spring mvc csv file upload error Required request part 'file' is not present

Tags: ajax, spring, csv, spring-mvc, file-upload

When I tried to upload a csv file to spring controller by Ajax I am gettig the error HTTP Status 400 - Required request part 'file' is not present

My ajax code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var form = $('#correctAnswerData');
  form.on('submit', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
    console.log("form data " + formData);
    $.ajax({
      url: 'answerdatacheck',
      data: formData,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      type: 'PUT',
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
      },
      error: function() {
        $('#errorMsg').html("An error occurred.");
      }
    });
  }
  );
</script>
```

and my controller code is

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/answerdatacheck", method = RequestMethod.PUT)  
  public String regiscorrectAnswerData(Model model, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

    if (file.isEmpty()) { 
      model.addAttribute("alertStatus", 1);
      model.addAttribute("alertMessage", "File is empty");
      return "jsonView";
    }
    model.addAttribute("alertStatus", 2);   
    return "jsonView";
  }
```

What will be the reason actually I have included the bean in application-context.xml

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <!-- max upload size in bytes -->
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="20971520" /> <!-- 20MB -->

    <!-- max size of file in memory (in bytes) -->
    <property name="maxInMemorySize" value="1048576" /> <!-- 1MB -->

</bean>
```

am I missing something.

Comment: try to change PUT by POST and check if works

Comment: Try to add `enctype: 'multipart/form-data'` to the ajax options

Answer (score 2):

It was just the error of accepting the file 
I just changed

```
 formData.append('file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
```

to

```
 formData.append('file', $('#file1')[0].files[0]);
```

and it got fixed